# Ethical issues related to refereeing for a top journal

Tags: peer-review, ethics, conflict-of-interest

Are there specific ethical issues related to being a referee for a top journal?

I was thinking that one might subconsciously be tempted to recommend a very good, but not groundbreaking, paper in one's own area just because it is the best there is in this area and because it helps maintain the visibility of one's own area.

Comment: To an outsider it might be even easier to recommend a paper not in their field, since they may find things new that would be well known to insiders in the field. In the end, as long as you are honest about the motives of the review (i.e. good review for a good paper and vice versa), you are fine. If someone uses reviewing to play games, they will be just like this conniving profs that everybody fears and sometimes hates. Forget ethics for a second. Is this how one wishes science to work and the community one wishes to work in?

Comment: 1) On the other hand, you also have an incentive to not recommend work that you think might be embarrassing to your field.

Comment: 2) Partly from experience, if a really top journal asks me to referee a paper, I tend to be quite suspicious, because I simply don't have the stature and reputation to convince them that a paper is worth accepting.  If I tell them it's the best thing since sliced bread, they'll think "What does this second-rate mathematician know?"  If I tell them it's not the best thing since sliced bread, they'll think "Even a second-rate mathematician doesn't think it's so great."  So, perhaps subconsciously, they're looking for an excuse to reject the paper if they send it to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your example is unethical since it seeks an unwarranted/unearned personal advantage. But that assumes a conscious choice.

Review the paper in front of you on its own merits. If it is very good, you can recommend it for publication independent of all other considerations. Not all papers published are groundbreaking. If that were a requirement, then journals would be very thin (and rare).

You can't, of course, *control* the subconscious. You can be aware of the issue that such might exist, of course. But if you are "getting the feeling" that you are advantaging or disadvantaging a paper based on external factors, then work to overcome it. In extreme cases, you need to inform the editor or even reject the review.

Review the paper.